# Line integrals and reparametrization

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

[image]

$C = (1,2,0)$, $B= (1,0,2)$.

**part B**:
I have that my parametric equations are
$x = 1$, $y = 2\cos(t)$, and $z = 2\sin (t)$.

**part C**: I don't know how to approach this. Do I start with the divergence of $G$ and then reparametrize with $\tau$?

Comment: Please take the time to enter the key parts of your question as text. Images are neither searchable nor accessible to people using screen readers.

Answer (score 1):

**Part B:** Yes, this parametrization is correct. But also don't forget to state the range of the parameter $t$, i.e. $\ldots\le t\le\ldots$, so that the trajectory actually starts and stops where it's supposed to.

**Part C:** Yes, as you said simply find the divergence of $G$, and then integrate along the path $\tau$. This means that you will substitute the parametric expressions for $x$, $y$, and $z$ into the expression for $\operatorname{div}G$. But also make sure that you set up the line integral with respect to the arclength $ds$ (as it's given), where $ds=\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dz}{dt}\right)^2}\,dt$.

Comment: Would my bounds be 0<t<1 or 0<t<$\pi$/2

Comment: @KirstinMorin: What value of $t$ gives you the starting point $C$? And what value of $t$ gives you the terminal point $B$? (Hint: the latter one is **not** $t=1$.)

Comment: Right, ok. So, [0, 2$\pi$]

Comment: @KirstinMorin: No. In fact, I've just noticed (sorry, I was in a rush and didn't see that at first) that in your first comment you already had the correct range $t\in[0,\pi/2]$. You should convince yourself why this is correct and your other two guesses are not.